# How to set format for time ticks in time chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to make a chart that maps integer values to days of the year. Pretty much like this one http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/financial.html, but I want the ticks to be only on the first of every month, and I do not want to display the year. (As it happens the year is not displayed in the link, but I think that's a space issue)

```
<canvas id="entries_by_doy" ></canvas>
var ctx = document.getElementById("entries_by_doy").getContext('2d');

var doyChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["2016-09-01", "2016-10-01"],
        datasets: [{
          data: [{t:"2016-03-31", y: 2},{t:"2016-09-01", y: 3},{t:"2016-09-2", y: 4}]
        }]
    },
    options: {
       scales: {
          xAxes: [{type: 'time',
                   time: { displayFormats: { day: 'MMM D'}},
                   ticks: {source: 'labels'}
          }],
          yAxes: [{ ticks: {beginAtZero:true} }]
        }
    }
});
```

I would expect `displayFormats` to specify the format of the labels, as ["display formats are used to configure how different time units are formed into strings for the axis tick marks"](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats) but it seems to get ignored.

Progress:
I can configure the tooltip format with `tooltipFormat` but I still need to configure the ticks on the x axis.
The length of the labels seems to influence the format as does the resolution.
[Here](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line-point-data.html) the labels are either a date or a time depending on width of window. 
I've tried using callbacks like this

```
callback: function(value, index, values) {
                 if([0,29,60,90].some(x => x ==index)){
                      return value;
                 }
           }
```

but not all ticks are displayed this way. I assume this is because an undefined is displayed (as nothing) instead of a close tick.
It seems that an update to 2.7.1 solves it...